# how to force tomcat to always redirect the 1st request to login page in case of form based authentication(tomcat realm)

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have a bit strange requirement. My application is written is **jsp** and server is **tomcat 7**. I am using **form-based authentication**. Here is my problem description.

Let's say I am logged in to my application in one of the IE browser tab. Now, I open a new tab and click the bookmarked application URL. As expected since I was already logged in and browser session is detected, instead of landing to login page, the application directly lands to status home page.

The requirement is that even if user is logged in one of the browser tab and valid browser session is available, the user should always be navigated to login page rather than directly landing to home page when tried to login in another browser tab.

Appreciated for quick help.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think your client fully understands what they are asking of you.

Imagine we could invent something quite nasty in javascript or with referer header, or something like that, in order to achieve what they want.  What if your user entered then different credentials in your tab #2?  Is your client aware that the session open in tab #1 is the same for both of them?

Make them understand they are trying to override a basic behavior of web browsers, and even if they did it would be useless.  Besides that, from a usability point of view, it would harm your application, since it would trick naive users into thinking they can open many sessions in the same browser instance...  good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Jorge_B.In the previous version when this application was without form based authentication, there were few checks like logged in browser session is being stored in backend till the user is not logged out and whenever it is tried to login in same browser session in a different tab, and if the stored session is still there that means user is already logged in the same browser and so a message is shown to user on login page which gives option to logout before re-login. And the 2nd one is if the login is tried in different browser with the same login id then the account is locked.

Answer (score 0):

Have the domain name (assuming that is the URL that is book marked) redirect to the login page and ensure this page is displayed even if the user is already logged in.
Then, if necessary (if they currently use a URL that's just your domain name) change your 'home' link, logo link etc to the URL of your home page.

Comment: That's my question actually i.e. how I can ensure that login page is always displayed. login page is configured in web.xml and tomcat redirects the request to login page only when it finds that the requested resource is a restricted one and user is not already logged in though please let me know if I misunderstood your advice.

Comment: Since the last referrer page is saved, when tried to login in 2nd tab, if the user is already logged in, the application is redirected as per last referrer page.